# Regex Pattern Construction

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to check if my string contains any of following characters `\:*?”<>|/.` 
and doesn't begin with ~
I'm not very familiar with regex, and could really use some help ;)

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: how about reading a [tutorial about regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) first ;-)

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do this with _one_ regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "test";
boolean status = input.matches("(?=.*[\\:*?\"<>|/.])(?!^~).*");
System.out.println(status);
```

`(?=.*[\\:*?\"<>|/.])` checks whether any of the mentioned characters are available for once.

`(?!^~)` means `~` is not at the beginning.

`.*` means to match the whole string as `matches()` method perform matching on the full string.

Comment: `^[^~]([^\\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\/])+$`

Comment: @deanosaur NO. In character classes, you do _not_ need to escape those; only the dash, [ and ] require special treatment.

Comment: But, all literal escapes require special treatment no matter where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Given your exact chars `\:*?”<>|/.`
this should work

```
 #  "^(?!~)(?=.*[\\\\:*?”<>|/.])"

 ^                                  # Beginning of string
                                    # Lookaheads to determine if;
 (?! ~ )                            # Not tilde at start
 (?= .* [\\:*?”<>|/.] )             # Contains at least 1 of these chars
```